# Does Rooftop Storm work with Arcane adaptation?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I had [Arcane Adaptation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bArcane%20Adaptation%5d) and [Rooftop Storm](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRooftop%20Storm%5d) in play, with the chosen creature type as zombie, would I be able to cast a creature such as [Nemesis Of Reason](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNemesis%20Of%20Reason%5d) for 0 mana? Or would that not work because Nemesis Of Reason would not yet be in play, therefore not yet a zombie?

Comment: See also [Conspiracy](https://scryfall.com/card/mmq/127/conspiracy), which does the same as Arcane Adaptation except for the card losing all other creature types.

Comment: Just edit the post if there's a grammar error.

Answer (score 9):

**Yes, you can cast any creature spell for {0} with that combo.**

As Arcane Adaptation states, every one of your creature permanents (on the battlefield), creature spells (on the stack), and creature cards (anywhere else) are the chosen type, Zombie in your case.

The process for casting spells is, in summary:

> 601.2. To cast a spell is to take it from where it is (usually the hand), put it on the stack, and pay its costs, so that it will eventually resolve and have its effect.  [..]

So to cast a creature spell, you put the card on the stack (where it's a Zombie spell because of Arcana Adaptation), then you determine and pay its costs. When it comes to determining the total cost of the spell, you can choose the {0} alternative cost granted by Rooftop Storm.

Comment: you could add the fact that cast triggers will apply as you are casting the spell. Cool for things like ulamog the hungry caterpillar....

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Arcane Adaptation adds the creature type, in this case it would need to be 'Zombie' to every creature on your field, all creature spells on your stack and all creature cards in your hand, deck, graveyard, and sideboard (outside the game when cards refer to that like [Mastermind's Acquisition](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMastermind%27s%5d%2b%5bAcquisition%5d)). This means when you announce the spell and put it on the stack, when Rooftop Storm checks the type, Nemesis of Reason will be a "Leviathan Horror Zombie" meeting the conditions to get the alternate cost of {0}.

This also works for an older card [Conspiracy](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bConspiracy%5d) which does not add, but replaces all creature types, in all zones, with the chosen type for your creatures, so in this case Nemesis of Reason would be just a "Zombie", still working with Rooftop Storm. It does not work for the third similar card [Xenograft](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bXenograft%5d), as Xenograft only affects creatures you control, so enter-the-battlefield effects will see it as a zombie, but casting effects will not, Nemesis will become a Zombie only as it enters the battlefield, too late for Rooftop Storm but cards like [Noxious Ghoul](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNoxious%20Ghoul%5d) will see the Zombie type for their trigger.